# Freezes application in button action

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I doing a game application using cocos2d.In this application two game are include together. When playing game i include a action for switching the game. when i use this button two or three times change the game but after that the game is freezes & not work any more until the game is close the game. If anyone have a solution than give me some information that how can i overcome in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have memory leak problems when switching games?

Its difficult to diagnose correctly with so little information but my guess would be that the switch process isnt done correctly and after a few times some memory/variables get corrupted